# Needs to access csv files in src/test/resource folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, classloader

I have the requirement to read CSV file from src/test/resource folder.

I provided the file at the root level and it is working fine. But I want to put all these files in src/test/resource folder.

```
String fileName = "Phone_valid.csv";
File srcFile = new File(fileName);
String path = srcFile .getAbsolutePath();

// path = C:\D Drive\Orange Codebase\dabek-data-processing\Phone_valid.csv


String fileName = "\\src\\main\\resource\\Phone_invalid.csv";
File srcFile = new File(fileName);
String path = srcFile .getAbsolutePath();

// path= "C:\src\main\resource\Phone_invalid.csv"


I want that path should be 
path = C:\D Drive\Orange Codebase\dabekdataprocessing\\src\main\resource\Phone_invalid.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first backslash. Does this work?

```
String fileName = "src\\main\\resource\\Phone_invalid.csv";
```

Comment: You want to access file in test folder. It means you have to run it in test context. How about running your code under `src/test/java` and not `src/main/java`?

Comment: You say 'it is not working by removing the slash'. What output you expect? What output you receive?

Comment: Actually i am getting path= "C:\src\main\resource\Phone_invalid.csv" but i need  C:\D Drive\Orange Codebase\dabekdataprocessing\\src\main\resource\Phone_invalid.csv.

Comment: What is it printing if you use the suggested fileName ("src\\main\\resource\\Phone_invalid.csv")? What is your working directory?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
File file= new File("src/test/resources/filename.txt");
```

**Note Avoid Space in directory name like  `Orange Codebase`**

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import java.io.File;

public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "src\\main\\resource\\Phone_invalid.csv";
        File srcFile = new File(fileName);
        String path = srcFile .getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("Path: "+path);
    }
}
```

Output of above code will be..

```
Path: E:\Orange Codebase\dabekdataprocessing\src\main\resource\Phone_invalid.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same by using below code

```
String phonePath= "src/test/resources/Phone_valid.csv";
File srcFile = new FileSystemResource(phonePath).getFile();

String path = srcFile.getAbsolutePath();

// path = C:\D Drive\Orange Codebase\dabekdataprocessing\src\test\resources\Phone_valid.csv.
```

Now, I am able to access the file from src/test/resources folder.